# NextJS + Typescript + ReactQuery Persistor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, react-query

I'm trying to use reactquery's persister with nextjs, but when I start the page it throws an error: " ReferenceError: window is not defined "

queryClient.ts:

```
import { QueryClient } from "react-query";
import { createWebStoragePersistor } from "react-query/createWebStoragePersistor-experimental";
import { persistQueryClient } from "react-query/persistQueryClient-experimental";

const cacheTime = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 5; // 5 dias

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      cacheTime,
    },
  },
});

const localStoragePersistor = createWebStoragePersistor({
  storage: window.localStorage,
});

persistQueryClient({
  queryClient,
  persistor: localStoragePersistor,
  maxAge: cacheTime,
});
```

_app.tsx:

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import "../styles/globals.css";

import { QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { PokeDataContextProvider } from "@/context/PokeData";
import { queryClient } from "@/services/queryClient";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <PokeDataContextProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PokeDataContextProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

I already tried using if(typeof window !== 'undefined') in all the places I could think of, and I couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: You don't need to use **window.localStorage**, just use **localStorage**

Comment: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Answer (score 4):

we allow to pass `undefined` as storage for SSR because restore from persistence happens in an effect (which doesn't run on the server) anyway:

```
const localStoragePersistor = createWebStoragePersistor({
  storage: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.localStorage : undefined,
});
```